# iPhone - Get controller which pushed me

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

When I pushed a controller, is there a way to get the controller which pushed it (without sending it)? Or the first one?

Thanks

Comment: In a well designed app, a view controller shouldn't know or care which view controller pushed it onto the stack. View controllers shouldn't communicate with one another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all view controllers from `navigationController.viewControllers` property. 
And the controller which pushed the currently visible controller is `[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:[navigationController.viewControllers count] - 2]`.

Comment: Caveat: not all apps have a UINavigationController.  In any case, can't you get which controller pushed you directly thru the parentViewController property?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift** version:

```
let numberOfElements: Int? = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count
let vc: ViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[numberOfElements! - 2] as ViewController
```